# How to SpanFromLeft when there is Alignment?

Tags: grid-layouts

```
Grid[
    {{AAAAA, SpanFromLeft}, 
    {aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc}, 
    {aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc}, 
    {aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc}, 
    {aa, bb, cc}}, 
    Alignment -> {{Left, Left, Right}}
]
```

In this case, the `SpanFromLeft` is not working when `Alignment` is used.
There is nothing in the "helpful" help file.

Sorry I was not clear enough. What I want is to make "AAAAA" to span the whole three column, like the 2nd output below, but to KEEP the rest of the rows using `Alignment -> {{Left, Left, Right}}`.

[image]

Or in general, how do I span a specific row?

Comment: It works ok for me. What output are you expecting and what version and OS are you using?

Comment: Works for me too. I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dstxk.png).

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I get the same and if I change to `Alignment -> {{Right, Left, Right}}` then I see `AAAAA` move to the right of the table/grid. Works as expected (V9, OS X).

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I have updated my post. I am using windows 7 X64, MMA 10.0.1 X64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SpanFromLeft` is working as designed and documented. You have specified that the first column must be aligned left and that is why your first row is aligned left. To move "AAAAA" somewhere other than what has been globally specified for the grid you need to make a specific alignment for that position:

```
Grid[{{AAAAA, SpanFromLeft}, {aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc}, {aaaaa, bbbbb, 
   ccccc}, {aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc}, {aa, bb, cc}}, 
 Alignment -> {{Left, Left, Right}, Center, {{1, 1} -> Right}}]
```

[image]

An alternative, which I don't personally prefer, is to use `Item`

```
Grid[{{Item[AAAAA, Alignment -> {Right, Center}], 
   SpanFromLeft}, {aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc}, {aaaaa, bbbbb, 
   ccccc}, {aaaaa, bbbbb, ccccc}, {aa, bb, cc}}, 
 Alignment -> {{Left, Left, Right}, Center}]
```

(I suspect this has to be a duplicate)

To address the comments, by default the alignment is to the centre so seeing a spanned example in the docs in which the element is centred is simply an example of `SpanFromLeft` working as documented with default alignments.

[image]

Comment: I have to say that when I was reading the help document, it 'looks' like it was 'centering' the cell. It was a bit misleading. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html

Comment: Speacially this example was misleading, `Grid[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, SpanFromLeft, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, Frame -> All]`. It made me misunderstood.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu by default the alignment is to the centre. You have specified non default alignments.

Comment: Yes, now I understand from your example. All I wanted is too keep (just the first row) AAAAA centered.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Then in the answer change "Right" to "Center".